# How to extract data of scatter plot from plot() in R

Tags: r

Below is a linear model, and we use `plot` to draw the "Residuals versus Fitted values". However, it seems we cannot directly extract the coordinate of points in this plot (although we can use `M1$residuals`). But this example is for the general scatter plot, so we need to "directly" extract.

I noticed other plots can extract data (e.g., `stats` attribution in `boxplot` [in this website](https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-extract-data-from-plots-in-r/)). Why the easiest scateer plot cannot (both NULL in codes below)?

```
x1 <- c(3.4, 2.5, 8, -4, 1)
y1 <- c(2, 3, 10, -1, 0.5)
M1 <- lm(x=x1, y=y1)
this_plot <- plot(M1,1)
this_plot
# NULL
this_plot$stats
# NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you plot data you *know* the data so there’s no need for the `plot` function to return it.

In fact, doing so would violate a software engineering principle known as “[Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)”, or SRP for short. Functions such as `boxplot` return the data because they perform two functions (and thus strictly speaking violate SRP): they *compute a statistic*, and they *plot* it. It is thus convenient that they return the computed statistic in addition to plotting it.

In your example, the computation is done by `lm` and (only) the plotting is done by `plot`. As you noticed, if you need the data, `M1$residuals` and `M1$fitted.values` provides it.